# Visual Studio settings - "Full Path" incorrect for references

Tags: c++, visual-studio, reference, static-libraries

I have a solution that includes projects A, B and C. I want A to reference B and C, so go into "Properties > Common Properties > Framework and References" and add them as references.

Although B works fine, when I add C as a reference, it gets the full path wrong. It seems to think that the static library is in project A's directory, when in reality it is in C's directory. So it is coming up:

C:\source\projectAfolder\libC.lib

when it should be...

C:\source\projectCfolder\libC.lib

Why would it be doing this? The full path is greyed out so I can't change it manually. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is pretty normal, project output is stored in the *solution* directory.  With high odds that you named your solution "projectA".  If you tinkered with projectC's "Output Directory" setting then you'll want to restore it.

Comment: Ok cheers -  I had not touched it so no idea why it was coming out wrong, but that was the culprit. Thanks!